# Getting into university - two variables distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If students want to get accepted to university, the chance to pass each stage is $0.5$. If you fail, you can't pass to the second stage and can't enter the program. If you fail the second stage, you can't enter the program too. We will assume a case of two people:

$X$ - The number of people failed in the first stage

$Y$ - The number of people failed to enter the program.

I need to find $P(X+Y≤2|Y≥1)$.

So $X$ is $0.5$ and $Y$ can be $0.5$ or $0.25$. Also, to calculate $Y≥1$, I did $1-(Y≥1)$ and got $0.75$. I'm not sure how to proceed to calculate $X+Y$ both. Thought to use binomial distribution to choose $0$ out of $2$, $1$ out of $2$ and $2$ out of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution is the following

$$P(X+Y\leq 2 |Y \geq1)=\frac{\frac{7}{16}}{1-\frac{1}{16}}=\frac{7}{15}$$

and this because:

the probability to have $P(Y \geq1)$ is the complement that both are admitted while the probablity to have $P[(X+Y \leq2) \cap (Y \geq 1)]$ are the cases circled in red in the table below.

This is a table of the bivariate distribution for your understanding (the yellow cells are the ones for which $X+Y \leq 2$)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Such integer problems, you can sometimes sovle "manually".
The only possibilities for the event $\{X+Y≤2|Y≥1\}$ are $Y=2$ and $X=1, Y=1$ since $Y\geq X$ and these variables are integer.

Now, calculate $P(Y=2 | Y\geq 1)+P(X=1,Y=1|Y\geq1)$

Now, use Bayes theorem:

$P(Y=2 | Y\geq 1)=\frac{P(Y=2)}{P(Y \geq1)}$
and $P(X=1,Y=1|Y\geq1)=\frac{P(X=1, Y=1)}{P(Y \geq 1)}$

Now, try to calculate the single probabilities.

In the case of two people, $P(Y\geq1)=P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)$.